# Is there a way to keep my navbar-right to the right and always visible at top of page when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Initial load:
[image: picture of navbar]

After scrolling:
[image: picture of navbar after scroll]

I'm trying to have a fixed nav at the top of the viewport. So as you scroll down the page the nav is always visible.  My problem is that I have my navbar brand set to the left of the nav and my links to the rest of my page set to the right. When I add position fixed to the navbar brand it works fine (the brand stays visible as I scroll down the page), however no matter what I've tried when I add position fixed to any other classes, id's, or elements involving the links set to the right, they end up getting fixed to the left and overlaying the brand or sitting directly under the brand.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I've tried adding position fixed to various classes within the navbar with no luck.  I also tried forcing the items to the right with float: right!important.  Most of the articles I've found suggest adding position: fixed to the .nav class, but when I do that the items are pushed to the left.  I included the html for my nav as well as the CSS for the nav, the background-video and the modal I link to in the nav just in case there is some reason this may be causing the problem.  Thanks for any help!  It's much appreciated.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#home"><h3>allicndev</h3></a>
        </div><!-- /navbar-header -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#about" class="db-line">About</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="active">
            <!-- <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top" title="Resume" data-target="#modalResume"><span>Resume</span></a> -->
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!-- /nav navbar-nav navbar-right -->
      </div><!-- /container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- /navigation -->
    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Resume</h4>
      </div><!-- /modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <embed id="modal-embed" src="assets/anresume.pdf">
      </div><!-- /modal-content -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div><!-- /modal-footer -->
    </div><!-- /modal fade -->
    <!-- /modal -->
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 30px;
  /* position: fixed; */
}
nav {
  height: 75px;
  display: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 10px;*/
}
nav.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
  position: fixed;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
a.db-line {
  transition: white .3s linear;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a > h3 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #f97f04;
}
/* a:visited {
  color: #EDCF10;
} */
.modal {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.modal.open {
  display: block;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  height: 75px;
}
.modal-content,
.modal-footer {
  width: 100%;
}
.modal-footer {
  bottom: 0px;
}
#modal-embed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
}
```

If possible I expect the brand ("allicndev") to be to the left top and the links ("about", "portfolio", "resume", "skills", and "contact") to be to the right top and the whole nav to stay visible this way as the page is scrolled through or links targeted to sections are clicked.

Comment: [navbar placement](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#placement)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the class fixed-top for fixed top navbar while scrolling

```
<div class="navbar fixed-top">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I gave this a try and it still doesn't quite work right.  This causes the links to the right to stay to the right, but they don't stay visible when the page is scrolled.  is there maybe some conflict that might be causing this that I'm missing?

Comment: sorry i can't understand your problem... you need your navbar to be fixed at the top and by adding the class "fixed-top" will do so. and the next thing is you ned your navbar to be fixed at right?? how come this ?? can you provide any screenshot regarding this

Answer (score 0):

The markup in your example is for Bootstrap 3, so that's problem #1, given that you've tagged this Bootstrap 4.

Assuming Bootstrap 4 is correct, adding the correct markup and classes seems to create what you're describing: https://jsfiddle.net/4rtjcpzm/1/

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">allicndev</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#about" class="nav-link db-line">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <!-- <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top" title="Resume" data-target="#modalResume"><span>Resume</span></a> -->
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul><!-- /nav navbar-nav navbar-right -->
    </div>
  </div><!-- /container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The `ml-auto` (`margin-left: auto`, if you check the source) class is what allows the links to slide all the way to the right. `fixed-top` and `sticky-top` will both stick the navbar to the top of the viewport.

`sticky-top` is probably the better class to use in terms of not needing to bump the body content down (the `padding-top` you see in the CSS part of the fiddle), but that depends on whether you know (or care) if most of your expected visitors will use a [browser that supports `position: sticky;`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

As an aside, do note that a > h3 (an H3 element inside an anchor element) is not (by default) valid HTML; `<a>` is an inline element, and `<h3>` is a block element, which is invalid according to the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element).